# Youtube recording disable others' internet connection

Tags: internet-connection, dd-wrt, youtube

Every time my wife does a recording from her laptop using the youtube video capture tool, it kills the internet connection for everyone else on the network (phone, tablet, desktop) -- every page I try to load gets a timeout error. I can still access my router webpage just fine though. My guess is that the recording is running up against the limits of my download bandwidth. Has anyone else run into this problem? What can I do to figure out what's happening?

Don't know if it helps, but my router is running dd-wrt, and everyone connects wirelessly

Answer (score 2):

I assume that by *"kills the internet connection"* you actually mean *still works but unbearably slow* (correct me if I'm wrong).

What you're experiencing is not unusual on connections where upload bandwidth is restricted (ADSL/VDSL connections immediately come to mind). It's also not unusual for some ISPs to provide rubbish upload bandwidth but excellent download bandwidth.

Good thing you're running **dd-wrt** on your router because it offers excellent QoS (Quality of Service) features.

Check it out here:

http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Quality_of_Service

Before you jump in, do that make sure you're running the latest version of dd-wrt and see if the issue persists.

Next step would be to use dd-wrt's QoS features to limit the upload bandwidth for traffic originating from your wife's MAC address (don't use IP addresses, they will change if devices are automatically assigned IP addresses by DHCP).

Let us know how you go.

Comment: Just to clarify by "kills the internet connection" I meant that I get timeout errors for every page I try to load. I am running the latest dd-wrt, so I'll give the QoS stuff a try once I get home tonight. If it helps, I can also get the exact timeout error code that chrome returns